# Are Kalki and Ganesha Puranas authentic?

Tags: puranas, ganesha, kalki

There are some issues in Kalki & Ganesha Puranas. Because, Kalki Purana mentioned past tences while Kalki is yet to appear and Ganesha Purana mentioned that Lord Ganesha will end Kali Yuga.

So, my question is, Are Kalki Purana and Ganesha Purana authentic scriptures?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely not. The Kalki purana is not even mentioned in the List of Upa puranas Given across scriptures, nor is it quoted to be among the upa puranas by any of the Smriti Nibandhakaras which shows that's most likely a work of later origin.

[image]

A perusal through the sample of upa purana lists given to us by the Puranas themselves or the citations of smriti nibandhakaras too does not give us the Kalki Purana anywhere.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Source - Studies in Upapuranas by Dr. R.C Hazra](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.52150/page/3/mode/2up?view=theater)

One can go through all the lists mentioned in the above at one's leisure.

There is however a 'Ganesaka Purana' mentioned in the list of upapuranas given the Varunopapurana which is most likely hinting towards the Ganesha purana. However it's complete absence in other lists also leaves it's authenticity as subject to doubt.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the total number of Upapuranas? Obviously, it would be more than 18, if you combine entries from all the lists. Is there any estimate given in that book?

Comment: Haven't Come across any numerical estimate in the book. Indeed it is admitted that the number far exceeds 18 though. The lists given by different puranas as well as smriti nibandhakaras aren't consistent with each other so such a thing is to be expected.

Comment: List of Upapuranas provided in the Puranas doesn’t seems to be reliable, for the variation in lists shows they have been modified by scribes throughout the ages. Texts like the Devipurana & Vishnudharmottara Purana are never mentioned in these lists, but they have been extensively quoted by ancient & well-reputed authorities like the Krityakalpataru & Chaturvargachintamani.

Comment: A few lists mention an upapurana by the name of 'Bhagavata' which I guess can be taken as a reference to devipurana? Pretty sure Vishnudharmottara too is mentioned in one of the several lists given in the book. I have only posted a small sample of them in the answer for a reference.

Comment: No. There are 3 distinct Upapuranas which often get confused to be one book -Devibhagavata, Mahabhagavata & Devipurana. The identity of the Bhagavata Upapurana is debatable.

Comment: I am aware of that.... The thing is none of the lists which are mentioned in any of the scriptures mention the terms like 'mahabhagavata' and so on by which they are generally known. Padma purana at one instance mentions a 'Daurga' purana (i.e. Purana dedicated to durga) but it's impossible to tell which of the 3 Devi related texts it's talking about